# spring 3 auto form field validation with file upload

Tags: java, spring

I was using JSR 303 validation with hibernate validator to have fields validated automatically by specifying @Valid on the controller method. Validation was working fine. I have know added an upload field to the form and have added a @RequestParam("file") as a MultipartFile file.  Now it works only if all fields are valid on submission otherwise I get a 404 (Bad Request).  If I remove the @Valid annotation I get the javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException with all the validation violations with Status 500.

I'm using Spring 3.2

my form:

```
    <form action="#springUrl("/admin/stores/save")" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Name: 
  #springBind( "store.name" )
  <input type="text" 
    name="${status.expression}" 
    value="$!status.value" /><br>
......
   <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*">

  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute Store store, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Failed");
            model.addAttribute("store", store);
            return "admin/stores/form";
        } else {
                .....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem is in method argument order. `@ModelAttribute` must be followed by `BindingResult` argument. Look at [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) and check also *Example 17.1. Invalid ordering of BindingResult and @ModelAttribute*.

. You also should add `MultipartFile` to form class (`Store`) if it is part of it.

```
Store {

    /* Your other fields */

    @NotNull
    private  MultipartFile file;

    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file= file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  Where can I find the possible different permutations of method signatures and the types of parameters and their order if enforced for the annotated controller methods?  I couldn't find details in the documentation.  Thank you again so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I think this is only case with enforced order. But you can find whole rules about parameters on above link (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) where you should read whole section _Supported method argument types_. For this case there's a paragraph that says: _org.springframework.validation.Errors / org.springframework.validation.BindingResult validation results for a preceding command or form object (the immediately preceding method argument)._